# Testing a member function which works on member variables

Tags: c++, googletest

I have a class `Addition` given below

```
class Addition 
{
private:
    int x;
    int y;
public:
    Addition(int a, int b)
    {
         x = a;
         y = b;
    };
    int AddtwoValues()
    {
          return (x + y);   
    }
};
```

To test the function `AddtwoValues`

```
#include <limits.h>
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "Addition.h"

class AdditionTest : public ::testing::Test {
 protected:
  virtual void SetUp() {
  }

  virtual void TearDown() {

  }
};

TEST_F(AdditionTest,twoValues){
    Addition addition(5,4);
    EXPECT_EQ(9,addition.AddtwoValues());
    EXPECT_EQ(5,addition.AddtwoValues());
}
```

Is the above an acceptable way to test the function `AddtwoValues()`. My question is since the parameters to `AddtwoValues()` are member functions of the `class Addition` should `AddtwoValues()` be parametrized? Is it a good coding practice ? especially if the member variables are more complex than two integers.

Comment: There is no "there" there. There is no object, and thus there is no `x` or `y` members to access in the static member function `AddtwoValues`. Therefore, the source is invalid, so I doubt any functional tests would be acceptable, no matter how they're implemented.

Comment: @WhozCraig - Plese see updated code. I have added a constructor for `class Addition`

Comment: Yeah, I saw it. It still isn't valid C++. [see it not-so-live](https://ideone.com/GxmRhq). I'm pretty sure you're looking more for [something like this](https://ideone.com/qBuy6s).

Comment: @WhozCraig - I have updated the question and forked the ideone and fixed it. https://ideone.com/irZk6w

Comment: Don't edit your questions like that, it makes the top answer sound wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Without discussing, why you would want to write a class to add two values, your Addition class isn't valid that way. The member function `AddTwoValues` is declared static, which means it operates on class level, not on each object. You therefore have no access to the two non-static members `x` and `y` which are declared non-static and therefore exist for each object you create. Change your code like this:

```
class Addition 
{
private:
    int x;
    int y;
public:
    public Addition(int a, int b)
    {
         x = a;
         y = b;
    }

    int AddtwoValues()
    {
          return x + y;   
    }
};
```

And you should be fine. For all the details on `static` members see here:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static

Regarding "best-practice": With such a small example for a rather trivial task, it is hard to say, in principle there is nothing wrong with it, including the test.

Answer (score 0):

> Is the above an acceptable way to test the function `AddtwoValues()`

In essence, it would be a perfectly fine test, except that you call     `AddtwoValues()` twice, expecting different results, which is bound to fail...

> [S]hould `AddtwoValues()` be parametrized? Is it a good coding practice ? especially if the member variables are more complex than two integers.

I'd argue that, if you want complete coverage, you should add at least one second test with different values for `x` and `y`. Otherwise the code might (accidently) be changed to

```
int AddtwoValues()
{
      return 9;   
}
```

and your sole testcase of `EXPECT_EQ(9,addition.AddtwoValues());` would pass without detecting the issue.